# Bluetooth cannot be started

Tags: bluetooth

Using Raspbian Lite on my RaspberryPi 4. Havent been able to get the Bluetooth working.

I tried

```
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

but

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When I start the bluetoothctl via `sudo bluetoothctl`, to my knowledge, it should start right away with

```
Agent registered
```

However, this is the terminal in and output:

```
>>> sudo bluetoothctl
>>> [bluetooth]# agent on
>>> Agent registration enabled
>>> [bluetooth]# default-agent
>>> No agent is registered
>>> Agent registration enabled
>>> [bluetooth]# power on
>>> No default controller available
```

How can I register an agent?

Edit:

Some extra info: I'm using a RaspberryPi 4 with Raspbian Lite installed.

Answer (score 1):

I did not think you needed sudo for bluetoothctl and normally you would do the power on command as the first step.

I do not have a Pi handy at the mo to test though.